# How to prevent IntCtrl() ignoring SetForegroundColour

Tags: wxpython

When changing the foreground colour of an IntCtrl it acted as if it was not set on every subsequent update, as the colour of the text reverted back to black.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while to find the answer, so if you have a similar issue the answer lies in default_color and oob_color.
Define it similar to this:
`self.Client_rate = ic.IntCtrl(self.panel3,-1,value=0,size=(25,22),default_color=self.txt_colour,oob_color="red")`

Then if you need to change the foreground colour alter like this:
`self.Client_rate.SetColors(default_color=self.txt_colour, oob_color="red")`

I trust this helps someone. Note: requires the spelling "color"!